# GIT SVN Clone - how to set the output/results folder

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm able to complete the conversion, but don't like the resulting folder structure. The repository I'm converting to GIT is a Visual Studio Solution that contains about 10 Projects.

The commands I'm using are:

```
git svn init https:/svn.example.com/:8443/svn/myrepo --no-metadata
git config svn.authorsfile ./users.txt
git svn fetch
```

The operation completes with a structure like this:

```
.git
trunk
    Project 1
    Project 2
    ...
    Solution.sln
```

I would like to eliminate the output subfolder (`trunk/`) completely, like this:

```
.git
Project 1
Project 2
...
Solution.sln
```

I don't seem to be seeing the option to set the output folder. How can trunk/ be eliminated?

Comment: Try `git svn clone https:/svn.example.com/:8443/svn/myrepo --authors-file=users.txt --no-metadata --trunk=trunk`. This sets `trunk` as a branch, not a directory. See [`--trunk`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt--Tlttrunksubdirgt)

Comment: By adding this it looks like I'm basically moving the .git folder into to the trunk/ folder? I think that'll work, too! Will give it a try and update the thread.

Comment: Apparently, my last comment is a wrong assumption. I ran the command with --trunk=trunk and .git was initialized in the same location. So, my second assumption is that --trunk= should be set with a fully qualified path? I tried a relative path of ./ earlier and it made no difference to output structure.

Comment: Try `--trunk=/svn/myrepo/trunk` or even `--trunk=https:/svn.example.com/:8443/svn/myrepo/trunk`

Comment: `--trunk=.` worked (I think ... it's running now, but looks good so far). Thank you!